# How can i convert an image into map tiles for leafletJS

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, leaflet, tiles

I'm trying to make it so that people can upload an image onto my site and have it converted into tiles for leaflet that can be used for a custom interactive map. The images are maps from games, not real geographical data. I've been looking around and I cant find a way to slice up the images into the tiles that are usable in leaflet directly through JS. I've found plenty of standalone programs but they won't do the job in this situation.

Comment: You may want to ask this question on gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has been asked already at https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285483/how-can-i-convert-an-image-into-map-tiles-for-leafletjs

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could just feed it through the *iconURL*; with something like below?

```
var UserIcon = new LeafIcon({
    iconUrl: 'http://www.website.com/icons/' + userID, // sample, craft user media URL
  className: 'UserIcon',
});
```

Comment: The maps may be very large and better to have in tiles for efficiency.